# Django Project : Custom Admin Templates are not getting loaded on an AWS ElasticBean server

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, django-templates, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have developed a django project and am overriding the admin templates. The changes are working fine in localhost but when I pushed the project to aws elastic beanstalk (AWS EC2 Ubuntu) server the modified admin templates are not loading.

Folder structure to project looks like:

```
--Project-Folder
  --manage.py
  --templates
    --admin
      --app
        --model
          change_list.html
  --app
    --templates
```

Settings.py Looks like

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media'
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

change_list.html looks like:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block extrastyle %}
{{ block.super }}
<style>
    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 50%; /* Full width */
        height: 50%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
      }
      
      /* Modal Content/Box */
      .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
      }
      
      /* The Close Button */
      .close {
        color: #aaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      
      .close:hover,
      .close:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
</style>
{% endblock %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'admin:bulk_upload' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                <input type="submit" value="upload" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="myBtn" class="historylink">Bulk Upload Questions</a>
    </li>
    <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

    </script>
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Kindly Help.

Comment: can you provide the error log ?

Comment: please follow link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WUknWB1oHxaJqkYL5vtV9IMq2tu8jDfn/view?usp=sharing to get the build logs